# How to replace existing bean with a spy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, replication

I'm using Mockito to test a replication library, in tests I'm mocking a DAO. However, the library is constructed in a way that it scans all available DAOs, as a result of that I get multiple beans (mocked one and not mocked one).

I am creating a spy of bean like that:

```java
@Bean
@Primary
@Autowired
public DAOBean daoBean (DAOBean dao){
    return Mockito.spy(dao);
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to somehow put my mocked bean instead of existing one and not just create a new one

pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the original bean is not created during tests you can

1. Run tests with a Spring profile for example `test` using `@ActiveProfiles("test")`
2. Annotate original bean with `@Profile("!test")`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@MockBean` in the test class instead.

`MockBean` annotation is located in `spring-boot-test` maven artifact.

You need to add either `spring-boot-starter-test` or `spring-boot-test` to your `pom.xml` in order to use `MockBean`.

Reference: [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html)

Comment: Isn't it SpringBoot annotation? the project im working on using only Spring-core and i cannot change it

Comment: It's in `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito` package and can be found in `spring-boot-starter-test` artifact. If you are limited in dependency update, you should show `pom.xml` of your project, too.

Comment: if I understood correctly `<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>` needs more dependencies for it to work, I can add dependencies scoped as test. I also added my pom.xml to the question

Comment: Yes. You need to add either `spring-boot-starter-test` or `spring-boot-test` to your `pom.xml` in order to use `MockBean` annotation. I will update the answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why you try to mock your DAO inside your Constructor.

Normally, it's the other way around - you would instantiate a Spy of your real Object by supplying your DAO as argument of the `spy()`-method.

```
class DAOTest {

    @Test
    void givenDao_whenDoingSomething_thenOk() {
        DAOBean testBean = Mockito.spy(new DAOBean());
        // ... assertions ...
    }
}
```